# Better way to matching pairs from array of users in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How to generate random unique pairs from array of users?

For example, we have 10 users and we must generate something like this:

- user 1 have to play with user 3
- user 2 have to play with user 6

etc.

Also, what should I do, if there's odd number of players?

Comment: _"what I should to do, if I have odd number of players?"_ – that's not a technical problem.

Comment: I mean, what I have to expect when we have odd numbers of players. Now I see it, last guy in array - alone [...[11, 1], [10]].
And yes, it's more about rules of the game...

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to generate random (unique) pairs between users (for game)

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [[5, 4], [1, 3], [6, 2]]
```

Reference:

- [Array#`shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-shuffle)
- [Enumerable#`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

> Also, what I should to do, if I have odd number of players?

Set even number of players to play and do nothing with the reminding one until new player shows up? :)

Comment: Thanks! It was easy. I do not know why, but I'm tried to do it with "permutation" and "unique". Have to go outside and breath little bit :D